# Session data ci3 base controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, controller, radix

I have this on my controller named pages(i use it as a terminal to branch out to all views)

```php
class pages extends MY_Controller 
{
    public function verification()
    {
        $session_data = $this->is_logged_in();

        print_r($session_data);

        if($this->is_logged_in())
        {

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, i have a line 'print_r' on the session_data, i got some results the problem is it always returns only '1'.

This is the function on my base controller.

```php
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    
    public function is_logged_in()
    {
        $user = $this->session->userdata();
        return isset($user);
    }  
}
```

And this is the code block after logging in creating the session data on my authenticator controller.

```php
Class user_authentication extends MY_Controller 
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username','required|trim|min_length[8]|max_length[24]|is_unique[user.username]', [
            'required' => 'You have not provided %s.', 
            'is_unique' => 'This %s already exists.'
        ]);    
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[8]|max_length[16]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|min_length[6]|max_length[30]|is_unique[user.email]', [
            'required' => 'You have not provided %s. ', 
            'is_unique' => 'This %s already exists.'
        ]);
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('type', 'Account Type', 'trim|required|min_length[1]|max_length[1]', [
            'required' => 'please select: 1 - normal, 2 - trainer'
        ]);
        
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('', '');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('templates/navigation');
            $this->load->view('pages/login');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
        else
        {
            $data = [
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'type' => $this->input->post('type'),
            ]; 
            
            $result = $this->Account_model->create_account($data);

            if($result == true)
            {
                $data['message_display'] = 'Registration Successful';

                $this->load->view('templates/header');
                $this->load->view('templates/navigation');
                $this->load->view('pages/homepage',$data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');    
            }
            else
            {
                $data['message_display'] = 'Username and/or Email already exists';

                $this->load->view('templates/header');
                $this->load->view('templates/navigation');
                $this->load->view('pages/login',$data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
            }
        }
    }
    
    public function login()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim|min_length[8]|max_length[24]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|min_length[8]|max_length[16]');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('templates/navigation');
            $this->load->view('pages/login');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
        else
        {
            $data = [
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'), 
                'password' => $this->input->post('password')
            ];
            $result = $this->Account_model->login_account($data);
            
            $this->session->set_userdata('isloggedin', [
                'username' => $result['username'], 
                'email' => $result['email'], 
                'type' => $result['type']
            ]);

            $data['title'] = 'home';

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('templates/navigation');
            $this->load->view('pages/home');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
    }
}
```

There are some stuff that are basically useless as of right now but i'm putting them there for future uses. like the $data['title'] gonna use it as a placeholder for the title on the head of each view since i am using templates.

Am i doing something wrong? Why does when i print_r the session data from MY_Controller it only returns '1'.

I've been looking at guides but most of them are outdated and i am probably using deprecated stuff from past versions, if so kindly point them out, i want to practice coding neat and clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach won't work that way because userdata returns an array with at least one key called **__ci_last_regenerate** (i'm not sure which CI version you use but if you autoload the session library you would always get an result here)

Set an extra key **isLoggedin** and you'll be fine.

Your login function:

```
public function login()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim|min_length[8]|max_length[24]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|min_length[8]|max_length[16]');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('templates/navigation');
        $this->load->view('pages/login');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');}
    else
    {
        $data = array('username' => $this->input->post('username'), 'password' => $this->input->post('password'));
        $result = $this->Account_model->login_account($data);

        if ($result)
        {
            $session_data = array('username' => $result['username'], 'email' => $result['email'], 'type' => $result['type'], 'isLoggedin' => true);
            $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);

            $data['title'] = 'home';
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('templates/navigation');
            $this->load->view('pages/home');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }

    }
}
```

and your controller

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function is_logged_in()
    {
        return $this->session->userdata('isLoggedin');
    }  
}
```

With this approach you get either a correct value or NULL which returns true or false;

> For more information you can take a look here
>   https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#CI_Session::userdata

Comment: Sorry for the super late reply.

What do you mean by setting another key?

You mean to set another array_key in my session? as 'is_logged_in' to 1 or 0 or true or false?

Comment: in order to gv you an accurate answer you've to show me your model ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print all your session data use this

```php
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
```

and this part

```php
public function is_logged_in()
{
    $user = $this->session->userdata();
    return isset($user);
}
```

will return 1 or 0;